# Why the file is not created

Tags: java, file

I'm creating a directory and then a file. The problem is that the directory is created but the File is not.

When I'm doing this I'm creating and it prints out that "Successfully created new file: and the name of the file.

Can anyone help understand why?

```
public class Main 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);
        boolean success = false;
        GetFiles getFile = new GetFiles();
        System.out.println("Enter path of directory to create");
        String dir = reader.nextLine();

        // Create a new directory in Java, if it doesn't exists
        File directory = new File(dir);
        if(directory.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Directory already exists");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Directory not exists, creating now");
            success = directory.mkdir();
            if(success)
                System.out.println("Successfuly created new directory");
            else
                System.out.println("Failed to create new directory");
        }

        // Creatning new file in Java, only if not exists
        System.out.println("Enter file name to be created");
        String filename = reader.nextLine();

        File f = new File(filename);
        if(f.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("File already exists");
        }

        else 
        {
            System.out.println("No such file exists, creating now");
            success = f.createNewFile();
            if(success)
                System.out.printf("Successfully created new file: : %s%n", f);
            else
                System.out.printf("Failed to create new file: %s%n", f);
        }

        reader.close();
        getFile.getAllFiles(directory);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are not creating the `File` _inside_ the directory - you are creating it _next to_ the directory.

Comment: your example does not compile as the GetFiles class is not defined.

Comment: You're probably not looking at the right place. Instead of printing `f`, print `f.getAbsolutePath()`.

Comment: your code is correct and working as expected. May be you are looking your file at wrong location as Boris hinted. Or there might be some other problem that is not clear with the information you provided.

Comment: GetFiles is in another java folder (Other class) but this is not

Comment: @JBNizet you were right :D, the file was created in the directory were project was created, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is completely working. It actually creates the file. You can see the created file in your java project.

Just add this line of code and it will work as you wish.

```
filename = dir + "\\" + filename;
File f = new File(filename);
```

Comment: If you are using eclipse you may have to refresh the project.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much man!!. that is what I needed.!! 
@johny 
Im such a noob ))

Answer (score 0):

I think the best ways --> to change the below lines:

#1.

```
 if(directory.exists()) 
   
  to below

 if (directory.exists() && directory.isDirectory())
```

#2.

```
  File f = new File(filename);
    if(f.exists())
```

to below

```
File f = new File(directory,filename);
if (f.exists() && f.isFile()) {
```